# Switch disks to persistent mode via vmware sdk api calls

Tags: c#, vmware, powercli

Update: The preferred solution would be something that uses the VmWare toolkit for .NET and achieves the following

One of the tasks that we now need to perform (if possible) is to toggle the virtual hard disks from non-persistent to persistent mode and vice versa.

I have tried looking for the correct API calls but haven't found any yet. Does anyone know if this can be done via the API calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't done this exact operation, I have done similar operations through the ReconfigVm task: http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vim.VirtualMachine.html#reconfigure

You will need to set up a VirtualMachineConfigSpec with an upodated VirtualDevice whose VirtualDeviceBackingInfo has the desired persistence type in its diskMode attribute.  The data objects are documented here:

http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vim.vm.ConfigSpec.html

http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vim.vm.device.VirtualDevice.html

http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vim.vm.device.VirtualDevice.BackingInfo.html

Comment: Many thanks Mark. I am trying to set this up but there isn't much documentation on how to set the desired persistence type on the diskMode attribute. Would you be able to post a quick code snippet on how to do this please?

Comment: I have gotten to the point where I can create a config spec and call a Reconfig_VM task. When I look at the VMWare Console, the task even gets fired. But the disk modes do not toggle. Do you know the right value for the DiskMode property?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [VMware vSphere PowerCLI Cmdlets Reference](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/index.html), this should do the job:

```
Get-HardDisk -VM $myVM | Set-HardDisk -Persistence "Independent(Non)Persistent"
```

Comment: I am actually using c# for my API calls. I will try this out after converting into equivalent C# code and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't find anything in the VMWare.Vim dll which would allow me to do something similar. Unfortunately I can not use powershell code due to some coroporate restrictions. Would you know if I can do this via using VMWare.Vim dll and C#?

Comment: Is there a way to view the code for this cmdlet somehow using reflector or something?

Comment: First, the question is tagged as `powercli` and not `C#`. If you'd like to automate vmware with C# you should look up for VIX API (http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/). It has bindings for COM, which makes it useable through dot.net framework.

Comment: I have updated the tags to reflect what I want done better. I did try the documentation but it isn't the best written in the world. I posted the question here as I need additional help in getting this done.